# ImageList byref or byval?

Tags: vb.net

I'm passing an ImageList to a usercontrol.

I have read that ByVal allows to change the object, but only ByRef allows setting the object to something else.

In my code I'm settings the imagelist to Nothing at some point in order to know that the imagelist has been destroyed.

Would it still be allowed to pass the imagelist as ByVal or should I use ByRef instead in this case?

"Nothing" is not an object, it's "Nothing", right?

Comment: Correct, "nothing" is not an object. But setting a variable to Nothing doesn't actually cause it to be disposed. It just means that the variable no longer refers to that object, so if no other variable holds a reference to that object then the object may be garbage-collected. But your question is unclear. Are you asking whether you should use ByVal or ByRef before or after setting a variable to Nothing?

Comment: Hard to make sense of this, ImageList is only useful as an image source for the ListView and TreeView controls.  So you'd normally assume that the UserControl consumes it and takes care of disposing it.  And thus you'd no longer care to know what happened to it.  Never assume that ImageList is a good substitute for List(Of Image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a variable as an argument to a method for a parameter that is declared `ByVal` then that variable will still refer to the same object after the method completes, regardless of what you assign to the parameter inside the method.  If you want to be able to change what the variable refers to by assigning to the parameter inside the method then that parameter MUST be declared `ByRef`.

If you have these methods:

```
Private Sub PassByValue(obj As Object)
    obj = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub PassByReference(ByRef obj As Object)
    obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

and you do this:

```
Dim obj1 As New Object
Dim obj2 As New Object

PassByValue(obj1)
PassByReference(obj2)
```

you'll find that `obj1` is not `Nothing` while `obj2` is `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, If you’re passing your `ImageList` as an argument to a method,  perform some logic inside that method upon the `ImageList` then set it to `Nothing` you’ll need to use `ByRef` so the changes to the `ImageList` can persist outside of the method. for any other case, you need not use `ByRef`.

Answer (score 0):

ImageList is a reference type, so when you pass it to a function or sub, it means you are passing a reference to the list, not a copy list itself. Any changes in the function or sub to the list that has been passed will change the original list itself. For example .. In the following code, even if you pass the `football` object (which is a reference type) using `byval`, and change the properties of the `bl` object, the `.Diameter` property of `football` will be changed as well even though you have passed it `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ChangeDiameter(football)
End Sub

Public Class Ball
    Public Property Colour As Color
    Public Property Diameter As Single
End Class

Dim football As New Ball With {.Colour = Color.White, .Diameter = 20}

Public Sub ChangeDiameter(ByVal bl As Ball)
    bl.Diameter = 5
    MessageBox.Show("Supposedly byval ball diameter =" & bl.Diameter.ToString)
    MessageBox.Show("original ball diameter =" & football.Diameter.ToString)
End Sub
```

Imaging a web page. This is your object. It has various properties such as text, margins, colours and all sorts of things.

Also imagine declaring a variable called `aWebPage` that contains a link to the website, and through this variable, you can change the website's properties. The variable itself only holds the link, not the web page.

If you then pass that variable that holds the link to another procedure and in that other procedure you call the variable `anotherWebPage`, you can, in the procedure use the `anotherWebPage` in the same way to change the properties of the web page, but what you are changing is still the website.

When you use `aWebPage` to view the properties of the website, its properties have also changed, because both `aWebPage` and `anotherWebPage` both hold the same link (or in .net, same reference) to the same web page, so changing one, changes both variables, because you are changing the same web page.

Clear? I suspect not - it took me ages to get comfortable with value types and reference types.